# Is Apache Beam the right tool for feature pre processing?

Tags: apache-beam

So this is a bit of a weird question as it isn't related to how to use the tool but more about why to use it.

I'm deploying a model and thinking of using `Apache-beam` to run the feature processing tasks using its python API. Documentation is pretty big and complex but I went through most of it, even built a small working pipeline, and it is still not clear this would be the right tool for me.

An example of what I need is the following:

`Input data structure`:

```
ID | Timestamp | category
```

`output needed`:

```
category | category count for last 30 minutes (feature example)
```

This process needs to run every 5 minutes and update the counts.

===> What I fail to understand is if apache can run this pipeline every 5 minutes, read  whichever new input data was generated and update the counts of the previous time it ran. And if so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Beam pipeline manually, it's expected to be started only once. Then it could be either a Bounded (Batch) or Unbounded (Streaming) pipeline. In the first case, it will be stopped after the all your bounded amount of data has been processed, in the second case it will run continuously and expect new data arrival (until it will be stopped manually).

Usually, the type of pipeline depends on data source that you have ([Beam IO connectors](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/)). For example, if you read from files, then, by default, it's assumed to be a bounded source (limited number of files), but it could be unbounded source as well if you expect to have more new files to arrive and want to read them in the same pipeline.

Also, you can run your batch pipeline periodically with automated tools, like [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) (or just unix crontab). So, it all depends on your needs and type or data source. I could probably give more specific advice if you could share more details of your data pipeline - type of your data source and environment, an example of input and output results, how often your input data can be updated and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Alexey. This clarifies some things but I have some follow up questions if you don't mind.  How exactly do I change the default assumption of bounded data when reading files?  And related to this, if it is now unbounded, with a 30 seconds window, what is the default trigger for the pipeline to finish executing continuously?

Comment: Well, it depends which IO you use to read files but, for example, with TextIO you can watch for new files matched by provided file names pattern and stop after some time if no new files arrive. See an example here: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.22.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html ("Example 3: streaming new files matching a filepattern.")